# "По коробу поскреби" - what does it mean?

Tags: значения

How to translate "по коробу поскреби" [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iu_MAZWLZs&list=PLnI9xbPdZUAmfrzf0gBsov_5ySlXQiSAu&index=2).

Comment: Here is also a variant «по сусекам поскреби» available with the same meaning.

Comment: "По сусекам *помети*" - сусек is an area in a room used for storing corn (seeds) or vegetables. It is much larger than a box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Короб is a kind of a box, that was used for storing things in old times. Поскреби is a suggestion to 'скрести', which means 'to scrape'. It's like "Scrape the bottom of the barrel", but instead of a barrel it should be some kind of a box.

The meaning here is that the box is empty, but maybe there's something left on it's bottom.

As for [сусек](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA) - this is an area in амбар ([granary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granary), a building to store grains or vegetables), it is much larger than a box, so old man ask his wife to "мести" (sweep) there: "по сусекам помети".